# Why was my post migrated to ELL?

Tags: discussion

The post: [Is this a complete sentence?: "The man is looking."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/422909/is-this-a-complete-sentence-the-man-is-looking?noredirect=1#comment1012537_422909)

No reason was given for the migration which was apparently decided by 5 people, all with the same primary interest (single-word-requests). It is not an ELL question. It is about verbs, meaning, grammar and grammaticality, syntax, semantics, meaning in context, all top tags, and more specifically it concerns complements and predicative complements, also approved tags on this forum. This is not about learning English, it is about grammar (prescriptive/ accepted/ common), it is about semantics, required syntax and idiomatic language.

ELL is not an appropriate funnel for questions people simply don't think are germane to ELU. Moreover, ELL is not a site that serves the interests of teachers and pedagogy. It serves overall as a place where learners can get their simple questions answered. Learners and teachers are really separate communities. It is generally inappropriate for teachers to discuss pedagogy amongst students.

As a teacher I need a sophisticated understanding of the English language in order that I may present my students with concepts that are simple and comprehensive while also being linguistically coherent. That is my purpose in addressing this crowd.

When I joined this forum I asked if this was an appropriate place for me and my interest in the English language, and I was very much welcomed and encouraged to participate.

[Is this forum appropriate for teachers of English as a second language?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10417/is-this-forum-appropriate-for-teachers-of-english-as-a-second-language)

I've made some mistakes, and some of my questions have been off the mark, but I don't think this post is one of them, considering the arguments I've presented. It is a deceptively simple question, as the comments indicate. At a deeper level I'm really asking about a pattern in the language where a verbs 'content' correlates to its need for complementation, even when there is sufficient context for a leap of interpretation based on surrounding context.

Comment: I don't think it's a big deal that it was migrated. People who answer at ELL might have a better sense of what you thinking of, about the meaning of such 'formally' correct sentences that are just not likely to be uttered (without more info).

Comment: This was clearly not a question about formal correctness.

Comment: I don't know why it was migrated, ask those particular people who voted that way. It would have been fine (to me) if it had remained. All I'm saying is that it's not a bad question on ELL. If you want to ask about the more linguistic general situation of 'subcategorization', ELU would be great.

Comment: Thanks Mitch, I appreciate the feedback.